# Team Foundation Server Build

Tags: tfs, team-explorer

i have found a queue build option in Team Founder .. so whats the exact purpose of queue build? we are able to build in vs itself...so just need clarification

Comment: Read the docs and the MSDN site maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build projects directly from visual studio, from a command prompt using msbuild - what TFS gives you (in brief) is the ability to set up continious integration, so a build is automatically initiated when a member of the team checks in - and you can hook in mail to notify team members if they broke the build.  You can also manage work items, sprints, etc.  Well worth the effort in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ...and i have succeed in tfs installation and learnt the functions.